# Automatic Conditional Format In Excel Depending On Different Columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a huge database, with a lot of data as you can see in this extract:

[image]

Then, my intention is to mark (with yellow) the next row with the same information as the row marked like "FIRST RESULT" in the image (in which indicates "SI" in the "APLICA SEGUIMIENTO" column). So, it would be depending on the column "APLICA SEGUIMIENTO" and on the column ("fecha"), these are the only difference between the two rows. In addition, I only want to mark the immediately next row, not all the rows, and I want do it based on the date ("fecha").

For this purpose, I have created an auxiliary column with a "UNIQUE ID" for every row and another column with this unique id only for the rows in which the column "APLICA SEGUIMIENTO" indicates "SI". I pretend to associate these extra columns to mark the interesting rows, but I don't know how to do it...

I hope you can help me.

I want to upload the spreadsheet but I haven't been able to do it...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is the second result the second result? from what I can see the values in two of the columns you mention (fecha and aplica seguimento) are different. Which columns should match?

Comment: That does not give us testing conditions. Again: which columns should match?

Comment: The second result is the second result because they are results of controls that we do at the same zone but on different days. When the result of the first control is out of specification we have to review the result of the next control. But if we don't have (in our database) a visual system to mark which is the next control, then we can't know which one is it... The form to determine which next result needs to be review in this control zone is to create the column "APLICA SEGUIMIENTO", and put "SI" in the first result. This is a mark to say, hey! you need to review the next result.

Comment: My intention is to match columns "UNIQUE ID" and "PUNTO SEGUIMIENTO" in a form to highlight the next result in the same zone but in different date (fecha), not all of them, only the most recent result after the out of specification marked with "SI" in the column "APLICA SEGUIMIENTO". Sorry, I have a clear intention, but maybe I can't explain it very well. thanks.